# Where is the storage account access key set in Terraform for access to the state file?

Tags: azure, terraform

We use Terraform to deploy to our Microsoft Azure tenants.

One of our environments connects to a storage account for it's state file. For that storage account we need to rotate the keys, but I don't understand where I am meant to set the new key. I have been looking at the documentation and it sounds like he backend setting does this, but I don't understand how it is done exactly.

The code we have looks like:

```
terraform {
 backend "azurerm" {
  resource_group_name = "ourresourcegroup"
  storage_account_name = "ourstorageaccount"
  container_name = "tstate"
  key = "terraform.tfstate"
 }
}
```

Please can someone help me understand where I set the storage account keys please.

Comment: The credentials aren't hard-coded in the Terraform code, so it appears to be following best security practices by specifying the credentials as either environment variables, or command-line arguments. That means looking at the code alone isn't enough, you need to look at any scripts/automation tools that run this code to figure out where you need to update the key.

Comment: There is a pipeline set up in Azure devops, but I can't see any reference to it in the yml file.